# Failed to send upstream message using XMPP protocols in fcm

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Sir I am trying to send upstream message from my android phone but failed to do so.Don't know where i am wrong.
Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;
private AtomicInteger msgId;
FirebaseMessaging fm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("hello");
    FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    msgId = new AtomicInteger();
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.click);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+msgId,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            fm = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance();
            RemoteMessage message=new RemoteMessage.Builder("<my sender id>@gcm.googleapis.com")
                    .setMessageId(Integer.toString(msgId.incrementAndGet()))
                    .addData("my_message", "Hello World")
                    .addData("my_action", "SAY_HELLO")
                    .build();
            fm.send(message);

        }
    });



 }
}
```

I had implemented onMessageSent() and onSendError() as according to docs but these methods were never called.Here is my messaging service class:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    Log.d("msg", "onMessageReceived: " + remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("test")
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));


    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0, builder.build());

}

@Override
public void onMessageSent(String s) {
    super.onMessageSent(s);
    Log.d("fcm", "onMessageSent: message sent");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "message:" + s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onSendError(String s, Exception e) {
    super.onSendError(s, e);
    Log.d("fcm", "onSendError: erroe");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error:" + s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

i am trying this from 1 week still don't know where I am wrong.Also there is nothing in logcat.please help.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set TTL at your message, For Example

```
   RemoteMessage message=new RemoteMessage.Builder("<my sender id>@gcm.googleapis.com")
                .setMessageId(Integer.toString(msgId.incrementAndGet()))
                .addData("my_message", "Hello World")
                .addData("my_action", "SAY_HELLO")
                .setTtl(86400)
                .build();
```

> setTtl(86400) this line is important ,hope it will helps.

Answer (score 1):

In an effort to optimize device resources especially battery the callbacks to onMessageSent and onSendError are batched so you may not receive a callback till you send around 10 or so upstream messages.

See the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/upstream#handle_upstream_message_callbacks) for more.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but again failed to get any callback even after sending 50 messages.please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an app server running some xmpp server to talk to the Firebase Messaging server.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to set Time-to-Live on your message. For example, `new RemoteMessage.Builder(...).setTtl(<time in sec>)`. I have not seen this behavior documented in the FirebaseMessagingService and/or Cloud Connection Server (CCS) references.